# update unique record and ignore duplicate record in msql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ignore duplicate record in update query. I want to ignore all duplicate value

I have try simple update but all record (include duplicate record)

Use Ignore in update -

```
update ignore table_name
    set col='value'
    where   matchkey = matchval
```

but no success.

Also used select where clause

```
Update table_name
    set col='value'
    where matchkey in (SELECT matchkey From table_name where matchkey=matchval )
```

But this say can't update same table

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.